# Cannot access external HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, mount

A few days ago, used my external HDD (a 2TB Seagate) in order to transfer some files on Vista. During that, I noticed some malfunctions on my system(it was running too slow, Windows Explorer crashed).

When explorer crashed, file transportation stopped. I was afraid, but I tried to access my files and it seemed to be working. I tried to open a movie(from Seagate) but it couldn't load. I thought of restarting, but this took sooo long...So I unplugged HDD and at that time it managed to shut down. I logged on `Vista` but the HDD couldn't be mounted. I plugged it but nothing happened. I unplugged it and I heard this specific sound that notifies that sth has been unplugged.

I thought of logging to Ubuntu 10.04 and see what I can do. I plugged the HDD, but I couldn't see it. I opened GParted but I couldn't see it either. I tried with Disc Utility and there it was! I tried to `mount` it but a got an error message stating that an error occured with windows, there is a file (0,0) that has problem or something like that. It suggested to log in Windows run `chkdsk/f` and reboot twice.

The thing is that I am somehow afraid to do so because I don't really know the impact on that. Plus I don't trust doing even a check on Vista

I risked it and I typed

```
chkdsk /f
```

on a `cmd`. I cannot, however, actually run it because I don't have admin privilleges. So from search I found `chkdsk`, I right cliked and selected `run as administrator`. It run but I got a message like NTFS file system. It should check at the coming restart.

At that point I am mistaken. I thought that `f` meant `F` but this is not the case here...

Does anyone have any suggestions and advice?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Actually I did `chkdsk F: /i`.Having HHD plugged, causes serious problems on my system's speed. I unplugged it. As soon as I did it, the `chkdsk` has finished. The answer is that the file system isn't `NTFS` but `RAW`. Doing a small search on what is that file, I came across a software `i Care data recovery`. While I run it, nothing really happens... Progress bar just stays in 0 for ever...

Comment: you should've left a comment under my answer - anyway, looks like your HDD is dying/dead. Have a look at some [data recovery questions](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery?sort=faq&pagesize=15) and see if you can recover the data

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to `mount` it but a got an error message stating that an error occured with windows, there is a file (0,0) that has problem or something like that.

That probably means that Linux has detected that the filesystem was not cleanly unmounted, hence Linux refuses to mount the filesystem to prevent any further possible errors.

> It run but I got a message like NTFS file system. It should check at the coming restart.

That indicates that the filesystem is mounted and in use, hence it cannot be checked. It's propmpting you whether a boot time chkdsk should be scheduled. Enter `y` as the option, it'll run chkdsk on next boot.

You can also force schedule a boot-time time by [*manually* setting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788091%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) the [dirty bit](https://superuser.com/a/479713/4377)

```
fsutil dirty set <drive>:
```

Reboot, the chkdsk should run.