# How does Windows 7 determine that a system was not shut down correctly (Kernel-Power Event ID 41)

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, event-log

I have a strange situation that Windows 7 thinks it was not shut down correctly, and gives me a warning in the system event log like this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504/de

What the KB-article does not tell is how Windows actually determines that situation. Does it parse its own system event log after reboot? Or where does it get that information from?

I am currently investigating an issue where I believe the system fails to write the system event log correctly (it stops having entries, although other logs like the application event log still have entries), and after a reboot, Windows thinks it has not been shut down correctly.

Does anybody have any experience with this? And can you confirm that Windows determines the previous correct system shutdown by parsing its own system event log on start-up?

Comment: Related: [How does the computer know that the PC was not properly shut down?](http://superuser.com/questions/479699/how-does-the-computer-know-that-the-pc-was-not-properly-shut-down/)